Angular 18 router provides wrong URLS for styles.css, main.js, polyfills.js
Angular 18 router provides wrong URLS for styles.css, main.js, polyfills.js
This path works fine:
http://localhost:4200/users
Related component:
/users/users.component.ts
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild, Input} from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatSort, Sort} from '@angular/material/sort';
import { User } from '../models/user.model';
import { UserService } from '../services/user.service';
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css']
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'name'];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<User>;
  users: User[] = [];

  constructor(private userService: UserService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private router: Router) {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<User>();
  }

  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort!: MatSort;

  @Input() filter!: User;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe((data: User[]) => {
      this.users = data;
      this.dataSource.data = this.users;
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    });
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data, filter: string): boolean => {
      return data.name.toLowerCase().includes(filter) || data.id.toString() === filter;
    };
  }

  getInputValue(event: Event): string {
    const target = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    return target ? target.value : '';
  }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
    // Update the URL with the new filter value
    this.router.navigate([], {
      relativeTo: this.route,
      queryParams: { find: filterValue },
      queryParamsHandling: 'merge'
    });
  }

  navigateToUserDetail(userId: number): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/users', userId]);
  }
}

Routes:
/app/app.routes.ts
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { UsersComponent } from './users/users.component';
import {UserDetailsComponent} from "./user-details/user-details.component";
import { CarsComponent } from './cars/cars.component';
import { CarDetailComponent } from './car-detail/car-detail.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'users', component: UsersComponent },
  { path: 'users/:id', component: UserDetailsComponent },
  { path: 'cars', component: CarsComponent },
  { path: 'cars/:id', component: CarDetailComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/users', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/users' }
];

The problem is with path: http://localhost:4200/users/1

user-details.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../services/user.service';
import { User } from '../models/user.model';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-detail',
  templateUrl: './user-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-details.component.css']
})
export class UserDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  user!: User;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'make', 'model', 'numberplate'];

  constructor(private userService: UserService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const userId = Number(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
    this.userService.getUserById(userId).subscribe(user => {
      this.user = user;
    });
  }
}

main.ts
import {CdkTableModule} from '@angular/cdk/table';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {bootstrapApplication, BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatAutocompleteModule} from "@angular/material/autocomplete";
import {MatButtonModule} from "@angular/material/button";
import {MatButtonToggleModule} from "@angular/material/button-toggle";
import {MatCardModule} from "@angular/material/card";
import {MatCheckboxModule} from "@angular/material/checkbox";
import {MatChipsModule} from "@angular/material/chips";
import {MatStepperModule} from "@angular/material/stepper";
import {MatDatepickerModule} from "@angular/material/datepicker";
import {MatDialogModule} from "@angular/material/dialog";
import {MatDividerModule} from "@angular/material/divider";
import {MatExpansionModule} from "@angular/material/expansion";
import {MatGridListModule} from "@angular/material/grid-list";
import {MatIconModule} from "@angular/material/icon";
import {MatInputModule} from "@angular/material/input";
import {MatListModule} from "@angular/material/list";
import {MatMenuModule} from "@angular/material/menu";
import {MatNativeDateModule, MatRippleModule} from "@angular/material/core";
import {MatPaginatorModule} from "@angular/material/paginator";
import {MatProgressBarModule} from "@angular/material/progress-bar";
import {MatProgressSpinnerModule} from "@angular/material/progress-spinner";
import {MatRadioModule} from "@angular/material/radio";
import {MatSelectModule} from "@angular/material/select";
import {MatSidenavModule} from "@angular/material/sidenav";
import {MatSliderModule} from "@angular/material/slider";
import {MatSlideToggleModule} from "@angular/material/slide-toggle";
import {MatSnackBarModule} from "@angular/material/snack-bar";
import {MatTabsModule} from "@angular/material/tabs";
import {MatToolbarModule} from "@angular/material/toolbar";
import {MatTooltipModule} from "@angular/material/tooltip";
import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';
import {provideHttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {AppComponent} from "./app/app.component";
import {appConfig} from "./app/app.config";
import {UsersComponent} from "./app/users/users.component";
import {CarsComponent} from "./app/cars/cars.component";
import {CarDetailComponent} from "./app/car-detail/car-detail.component";
import { routes } from './app/app.routes';
import {MatSortModule} from "@angular/material/sort";
import {UserDetailsComponent} from "./app/user-details/user-details.component";

@NgModule({
  exports: [
    CdkTableModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatSortModule
  ]
})
export class DemoMaterialModule {}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    DemoMaterialModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,

    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [UsersComponent, UserDetailsComponent, CarsComponent, CarDetailComponent],
  bootstrap: [],
  providers: [provideHttpClient()]
})
export class AppModule {}

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig)
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));

UPDATE:
index.html
<app-root></app-root>

UPDATE 2:
Working
index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>App</title>
  <base href="/">
</head>
<body>
<app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>


Put <base href="/"> into <head> of src/index.html file
